# Scroll left and right when hovering on arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, hover

So I am trying to simply scroll left and right when someone hovers over arrows. I forked another JSFiddle and copied the html/css from my website I'm trying to do this on. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/31hf4e0h/

Right now it scrolls all the way to the right when you hover over either arrow, but I want the #before arrow to make it scroll to the left. Is there an easy way to do this? Or a more simple way to achieve this effect generally?

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
var $container = $('#object-nav ul'),
    scroll = $container.width();
$('#after').hover(function() {
    $container.animate({
        'scrollLeft': scroll
    },{duration: 2000, queue: false});
}, function(){
    $container.stop();
});
$('#before').hover(function() {
    $container.animate({
        'scrollLeft': scroll
    },{duration: 2000, queue: false});
}, function(){
    $container.stop();
});

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is perfect solution for on hover left and right scroll. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neelu/jm33rjtj/6/)

```js
function loopNext(){
    $('#sliderWrapper').stop().animate({scrollLeft:'+=20'}, 'fast', 'linear', loopNext);
}

function loopPrev(){
    $('#sliderWrapper').stop().animate({scrollLeft:'-=20'}, 'fast', 'linear', loopPrev);
}

function stop(){
    $('#sliderWrapper').stop();
}


$('#next').hover(function () {
   loopNext();
},function () {
   stop();
});

$('#prev').hover(function () {
   loopPrev();
},function () {
   stop();
});
```

```css
#sliderWrapper {
    left: 40px;
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #999;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#next {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: #555;
    z-index: 1;
}
#prev {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #555;
    z-index: 1;
}
#imageSlider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#imageSlider img{width:100px; height:100px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageSlider">
    <div id="prev">
        <img src="" width="40px" />
    </div>
    <div id="next">
        <img src="" width="40px" />
    </div>
    <div id="sliderWrapper">
        <img src="" height="90px;" />
        <img src="" height="90px;" />
        <img src="" height="90px;" /><img src="" height="90px;" />
        <img src="" height="90px;" />
        <img src="" height="90px;" />
        <img src="" height="90px;" /><img src="" height="90px;" />
        <img src="" height="90px;" /><img src="" height="90px;" /><img src="" height="90px;" /><img src="" height="90px;" /><img src="" height="90px;" /><img src="" height="90px;" /><img src="" height="90px;" />
        
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll right, you still have to use 'scrollLeft', but you can scroll to right by specifying the number of pixels.

Try something like this:

```
$('#before').hover(function() {
        $container.animate({
            'scrollLeft': -100
        },{duration: 2000, queue: false});
      }
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! I tried something like that but must have had the syntax wrong.